# Finding the root of equation

Tags: r, equation

I want to solve the equation given below wrt c

[image]

where n=k=30 and x is given below.

I used the `uniroot` command in `rootSolve` package and following code but it gave me an error.

```
model <- function(c){
  sx <- apply(x,1, function(x) exp(c*x))
  numerator <- sum(sx[2:30])-29*sx[1]
  denumerator <- (30*29*(sx[1]-1))
  numerator/denumerator-0.2542
}
ss <- uniroot(model, c(0,1))
```

The root is known and 0.0331.

So where is my mistake? How to fix it?

Comment: The denominator is undefined for `c = 0`. Try `uniroot(model, c(1e-10,1))`